# Cross section of a 3d array

Tags: c#

Is there a way to do a cross section of a 3D Array?

What I mean is: Cut the array along the Z axis so you get a 2D plane of the X axis and Y axis.

I need to do this so I can store them as separate sections in an `ArrayList`, or even potentially a `List`.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us the data structure you are using to define your 3d array.

Comment: You can use a jagged array instead, if that is an option (like `int[][,]`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure C# has an out-of-the-box way of doing this, so you'd have to implement something yourself:

```
T[,] SliceThroughZ<T>(T[,,] threeDee, int zIndex)
{
    var xLength = threeDee.GetLength(0);
    var yLength = threeDee.GetLength(1);
    var twoDee = new T[xLength, yLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < xLength; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < yLength; j++)
            twoDee[i, j] = threeDee[i, j, zIndex];

    return twoDee;
}
```

Alternatively, rather than making a copy, you could implement a wrapper class with a two-dimensional indexer that simply queries the original array. You'd lose array-specific methods, though.

```
class ZSliceWrapper<T>
{
    public T[, ,] Source { get; set; }
    public int ZIndex { get; set; }

    public T this[int xIndex, int yIndex]
    {
        get // you could even implement a set.
        {
            return Source[xIndex, yIndex, ZIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK good, that is exactly how it popped into my head just after I posted this... Stupid brain, *Panic, Panic* *Post Question* *Brain finds answer*

Comment: Hah, I think we've all been there :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what is your **Z** axis is:

if you say have

`var array = new int[]{xAxiss1, yAxiss1, zAxiss1, xAxiss2, yAxiss2, zAxiss2...}`.

So if you want to *slice* this array on XY dimmension, just pick 1st and 2nd element from it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array `SomeType[,,]` of rank three, then the cut *perpendicular* to you z axis (that is parallel to th xy plane) comes easily by fixing one `z` (the "height" you want your cut to be in) and letting `x` and `y` run through their ranges.

For example

```
static IEnumerable<SomeType> CutInXYDrection(SomeType[,,] threeDimArr, int zValue)
{
  for (int x = 0; x < threeDimArr.GetLength(0); ++x)
  {
    for (int y = 0; y < threeDimArr.GetLength(1); ++y)
    {
      yield return threeDimArr[x, y, zValue];
    }
  }
}
```

**ADDITION:**
If you were to cut in the YZ direction instead, you could take advantage of the order in which foreach traverses multi-dimensional arrays (end of §8.8.4 in C# Language Specification version 4.0):

```
static IEnumerable<SomeType> CutInYZDrection(SomeType[,,] threeDimArr, int xValue)
{
  int oneLayer = threeDimArr.GetLength(1) * threeDimArr.GetLength(2);
  return threeDimArr.Skip(xValue * oneLayer).Take(oneLayer);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply hope this helps others, since my brain is retarded and managed to solve it just as I posted!

Comment: @Jeppe This will also flatten the slice into a single dimension.

Comment: @Rawling Yes, I thought the Original Poster wanted that because he talked about a "list" (which I interprete as one-dimentional).